# Was I using MariaDB or MySQL?

Tags: mysql, mariadb

An Ubuntu upgrade (to 19.10) messed up my database server. After the upgrade, the sql server would not start. So I installed MySQL but later realized that I may have been using MariaDB.

Is there a way to find out based on the table's content, what I was previously using -- if **MariaDB** or **MySQL**?

I have two folders in `var/lib/`: one is named `mysql` and the other is `mysql-10.2` (which kind of indicates that I was, at a given time, must have been running MariaDB 10.2 on Ubuntu 18.04); they both have the database files in them: `.frm`,`.MYD`, and `.MYI`.

I am thinking it would matter to reinstall the same sql engine. But reading more about that it turns out that as long as it is a newer engine it will be compatible.

I since tried to get the database working again, but without any success.

I tried to uninstall MySQL and MariaDB in order to freshly install MariaDB. But I somehow can't get it working. More on that front here on my [unix.stackexchange.com](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/550154/the-following-packages-have-unmet-dependencies-mariadb-server) post.

**Update**

running `dpkg --get-selections` I get

```
...
mysql-client-8.0        install
mysql-client-core-8.0   install
mysql-common            install
mysql-server-8.0        install
mysql-server-core-8.0   install
mysql-utilities         deinstall
...
```

Comment: Run `dpkg --get-selections` and see what you have installed.

Comment: @Zoredache see update

Answer (score 1):

If it is actually running, this may be the least invasive way of asking *it* what version it is:

```
mysqld --version
```

That should work equally well for either MySQL or MariaDB or Percona.  Example:

```
$ mysqld --version
mysqld  Ver 5.6.22-71.0 for debian-linux-gnu on x86_64 (Percona Server (GPL), Release 71.0, Revision 726)
```

Comment: The problem is that the server is not running. The only information I have available are the database files, and possibly some logs.